# FactoryGirl seems not to fill out fields

Tags: validation, factory-bot, sti

I use Single Table Inheritance, where the model producer is derived from the model user, which in turn is derived from contact. Contact and User have  some validation as:

```
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true, 
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

for the contact and

```
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

in the user model.

In my factory.rb I have FactoryGirl building a sequence of "producer" records as such:

```
factory :producer do
  sequence(:name)  { |n| "Producer #{n}" }
  sequence(:email) { |n| "producer_#{n}@example.com"}   
  password "foobar"
  password_confirmation "foobar"
end
```

Then in the spec I do

```
    let(:producer) { FactoryGirl.create(:producer) }
```

This doesn't seemingly pass the validation:

```
  1) Client
     Failure/Error: let(:producer) { FactoryGirl.create(:producer) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Email can't be blank,  
       Email is invalid, Password digest can't blank, Password is too short  
       (minimum is 6 characters), Password confirmation can't be blank
```

Are the fields not assigned in FactoryGirl?